# RN TextInput does not listen to returnKeyType changes

Tags: reactjs, react-native, textinput

I am trying to change `returnKeyType` prop of `TextInput` from `next` to `go` while editing, but it does not work. Please help to find a solution. Thanks

Comment: Provide some code or create a fiddle on snack.expo

Comment: <TextInput value={this.state.username} onChangeText={...} returnKeyType={this.state.password !== '' && this.state.username!=='' ? 'go' : next'} onSubmitEditing={ ... } />

Comment: I have 2 TextInputs - password and username. So the above provided code is for username TextInput. I check whether passpord and username are empty strings or not. If they are empty strings then I want to show `next` button, otherwise - `go` button

Comment: Facing the same issue, did you ever find a way to fix this?

Comment: nope, I did not